# How to ROTATE (NOT stack) HTML blocks in vertical order in CSS FlexBox in order of appearance?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, menu, vertical-text

Given a logical (search engine readable) HTML menu containing an unordered list menu wrapped inside a `<nav>`, starting with item Home and ending with item Blog. I have tried several things in pure CSS and HTML but cannot achieve what I want.

**https://jsfiddle.net/6zt3gfp4/**

What I would like, is this:

1. **Align the whole vertical menu to the top left edge of the screen, automatically.**
   Regardless of the number of and/or length of the list items contained in the `<nav>`!!
2. **Expand the clickable area of each underlined link to its entire blue block.**
   For ease of use when hovering and clicking a menu item.
3. **Ideally we should leave my broken start behind and opt for a FlexBox CSS design.**
   Perhaps that gives us all better flexibility for achievng this. That would be a bonus!

[image]

```css
nav {
  text-align:center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-240px) translateY(-100px);
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav li a{
  color: #fff;
}

nav li a:hover{
  background: black;
}

nav li.selected {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't play a lot with transformation. Use writing-mode then move the style applied to `li` to `a` to make the link area bigger.

```css
nav {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  background-color: blue;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* */
  transform: scale(-1); /* */
  margin: 5px 0;
}
nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background: black;
}
nav li.selected {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly in Firefox - don't know why. What seems to work in both Chrome and Firefox is to move writing-mode to the ul element and set the flex direction to row.

Comment: @Alohci oops didn't check FF. It's seems that removing display:flex also fixes the issue. Not need at end since the default flow could do the job

Comment: Wonderfully Elegant! Thank you! Answer accepted. Just a strange thing: in both your original and updated version there seems to be a pesky extra pixel of margin between the two last items! I can't get rid of it when setting the margin to 0. A thin white line can be observed between Blog and Contact in Chrome. Strange?! In Firefox the new version works perfectly! 
See old https://jsfiddle.net/dep0t3sv/3/  and new https://jsfiddle.net/vhm2Lno6/1/

Comment: Even when adding  `margin: -1px 0; border-top: 2px solid white;` to `nav li`, in Chrome the  space between the last two blocks is slightly larger... Strange. Am I the first person ever to have noticed this? I'm not sure therefore I wonder if I will be the _last_ person ever to notice this imperfection lol.

Comment: @Såm probably a sub pixel rendering issue. Unfortunately, we cannot control this. Either consider negative margin or add some box-shadow to cover that space.

Comment: Awesome idea, didn't think of that (box shadow of 1px with blur set to 0px), thanks!